# Best Practice: Including Library From Other Repo in PyCharm Project

Tags: configuration, pycharm, include, subproject

Imagine an application project that must include a subfolder, "**lib**", that consists of an other git repo project.  This **lib** project contains the libraries we use in all new projects.

How can I configure my new project to link to the local repo library folder, so that,

1. the git information for the subfolder containing the library
   project is not interfering with the main project git information?
2. Not include the subfolder in the new git structure?

I've temporarily copied all but the git folder from the subfolder project into my own 'lib' folder under the new project - but I am not sure that this is the best practice, as if the library project is locally updated, I would like the changes to automatically be included in my runtime when I am working on the local new project in which this lib folder exists.

Can you provide some best practices on how to best configure my project and PyCharm for such a scenario?

Thank you.